How to implement a multi-document application based on dialog (modal) windows in VUE?
Now I have a classic SPA application implemented using the VUE, VUE Router, VUEX, Vuetify stack.
Recently I saw an implementation of an interface based on editing data in dialog (modal) windows. As a result of studying these applications, I realized that these modal windows open depending on the value of the URL address, and they overlap each other (that is, many windows can be open at one time - a kind of MDI application for Windows).
As far as I understand, you need to somehow store a list of open modal windows in Vuex.
Tell me where to dig to implement the same interface on VUE or maybe there is already a ready-made solution?

It's unclear if you mean physical browser popup windows or overlay modals as these are totally different cases, but they both fit the description. You refer some example but you didn't post a link. Any way, the question is too broad, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Asking for libs isn't allowed on SO, and even in this case the answer could be totally different for Vue 2 and 3 as their ecosystems are different. There are things like vuefinalmodal but it's not a complete solution. Global store like Vuex is a reasonable place to interact with global things like modals
